# NoneType error when reading from long list Python

Tags: python

I'm not sure why this doesn't work. I'm trying to iterate from a very long wordlist and convert the characters to ASCII and then for each word add it to a list holding sets of the length of each word and a placeholder (0.0) for each character. I tried to fix it, assuming the "none" was being returned by the generator reading the file, but the error is instead in the list generators.   The traceback is:

```
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-180a2950dd2d> in <module>()
     35 for item in read_words(r"*pathname*"):
     36     if item is not None:
---> 37         inputs.append(set([len(item.split(","))].extend([0.0 for i in range(1, len(item))])))
     38 print(inputs)
     39 #fitness function

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Here's the whole code:

```
 import neat, random
#fast solution for iterating over large wordlist
# playing with the training data a bit

def convert(word):
    return [str(ord(i)/122) for i in word]

def read_words(inputfile):
    with open(inputfile, 'r') as f:
        while True:
            buf = f.read(10240)
            if not buf:
                break

            # make sure we end on a space (word boundary)
            while not str.isspace(buf[-1]):
                ch = f.read(1)
                if not ch:
                    break
                buf += ch

            words = buf.split()
            for word in words:
                yield word
        yield '' #handle the scene that the file is empty

asciilist = open(r"*pathname*", "w+")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for word in read_words(r"*pathname2*"):
        asciilist.write(",".join(convert(word)))

inputs = []

for item in read_words(r"pathname"):
    if item is not None:
        inputs.append(set([len(item.split(","))].extend([0.0 for i in range(1, len(item))])))
print(inputs)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, methods or functions which have side effects and modify the object in place (like append() or sort()) explicitly return None.

This is to prevent any confusion with the functional style (like sorted()), in which return values are newly allocated objects and the original is unchanged. [source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/4ai2y2/why_doesnt_method_chaining_work_in_python/)

you can add lists in python with the '+' sign if you want to do this in one line, as unlike extend, addition does not modify the original lists.

```
inputs.append(set([len(item.split(","))] + [0.0 for i in range(1, len(item))]))
```

I will also add though, it seems like either the "set" word or the "[0.0 for i in range(1, len(item))]" part needs to go, you are creating a list with multiple 0.0 only to take a set of it. As-is, you will not be representing a placeholder for each character.